# Get the actual width of a subview at runtime (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode9, swift4

Xcode provides a Segmented Control but I want a Custom Segmented Control with a selector that slides to each button when you press it. I use 3 views for it. One is the "main" view which I added two subviews. One of the subviews is the selector (UIView) and the other one is a UIStackView which contains the buttons. I use `selector = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width/CGFloat(buttons.count), height: self.frame.height))` for the size of the selector. When I use my class for a view in the storyboard everything looks fine. I made constrains for the superview, but when I start the app with a simulator I get the width which was set in the storyboard and not the actual width at runtime with `self.frame.width`.

I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGdRCUrSu94) video as a template.
And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UMBb.gif) is what it looks like when I run the app. The selector is not as big as one button and that's why I get this white bar on the right site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UIControl** inherits from **UIView** class which you can use **layoutSubviews** function for getting correct **Frame** after constraints applied

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
    //self.frame will be correct here
}
```

references:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol

Comment: Thanks, that help me out! Furthermore `layoutSubviews()` gets called when the phone rotates so it automatically adjust the width. Do you know if this method gets also called when you do some adjustments on the storyboard? Because it also changes the width of the selector when I resize the view there.

Comment: Okay, so it worked for me, but after a day everytime I select the my costum class in the identity inspector Xcode 9 is freezing. When I remove the function `layoutSubviews` it doesn't freez.

Comment: Make sure u have the word 'override' before the function  override func layoutSubviews() and make sure you are calling the  super.layoutSubviews()

Comment: I have written 'override' before the function and calling super.layoutSubviews(). It's still freezing

Comment: UPDATE - when I add constraints first to a view and then add the method Xcode is not freezing. But when I first add the method in my code without constraints Xcode freezes. Does anyone know why?

Comment: what Xcode version are you using? its probably a bug in the new Xcode update to version 9.1 and if the issue stays, report it to Apple https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Yesterday I was using Version 9.0 and today I updated it to version 9.1. Both version have the same problem. I will report it!

Answer (score 2):

Its looks like you are getting the frame before the Constraints are set, try getting the frame **viewDidLayoutSubviews** or **viewDidAppear** event

below are the events and the Constraints status:

- viewDidLoad -- Constraints haven't set
- viewWillAppear -- Constraints haven't set
- viewWillLayoutSubviews -- Constraints are setting
- viewDidLayoutSubviews -- Constraints are set
- viewDidAppear -- Constraints are set

Comment: I can't do that because my class `UICostumSegmentedController` inherits from `UIControl` and not from `UIViewController`, which means it doesn't have those functions